# NotificationManager.cancel(id) not working

Tags: java, android, notifications

This is my send notification method but the problem is i am getting the notification but not able to cancel it. i want my notification gets removed after 15 minutes and also after tapped by the user on notification.

```
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Recite Dua").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    alamNotificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

    long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
    alamNotificationBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);

    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");

    removeNotification();
}

private void removeNotification() {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        long delayInMilliseconds = 1000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                stopForeground( false );
                alarmNotificationManager.cancel(1);
            }
        }, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Use `PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)` to close it once the user taps it.

Comment: still notifications remains , i tried FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Answer (score 0):

Use `stopForeground(true);`
It clears notification which id is used in `startForeground` method.